# Is the order of values retrieved from a HashMap the insertion order

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying figure out the order in which the values in a HashMap are/can be retrieved. Heres the code snippet for the same.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       HashMap<Integer, String> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
       hashmap.put(1, "apple" );
       hashmap.put(2, "lemon" );
       hashmap.put(3, "orange" );
       hashmap.put(4, "banana" );
       hashmap.put(5, "litchi" );
       hashmap.put(6, "mango" );
       hashmap.put(7, "papaya" );

       System.out.println(hashmap.size());

       for (String key : hashmap.values()) {
           System.out.println(key);
       }
   }
}
```

### output:

```
7
apple
lemon
orange
banana
litchi
mango
papaya
```

The values are printed in the order in which they have been inserted. Is this true in general? I was expecting the values to be printed in an arbitrary order. This is using Java 6.

Comment: Just use  a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: @Raedwald Okay, but she did ask about insertion order multiple times, and it seems like LinkedHashMap is probably worth looking at.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> The values are printed in the order in which they have been inserted. Is this true in general? I was expecting the values to be printed in random order.

The `HashMap` API does not define the order of iteration.

However, if you look at the implementation of HashMap, you can deduce that there is a complex transient relationship between the iteration order, the keys' hash values, the order in which the keys were inserted and the size of the hashtable.  This relationship gets scrambled if the hashtable resizes itself<sup>1</sup>.

In your case, you are using `Integer` keys which means that the hash values of the keys are the key values themselves.  Also, you inserted the entries in key order.  This leads (fortuitously!) to the iteration order matching the insertion order.  But if you kept inserting more keys, you would find that the iteration order "wraps around".  Then as the table goes through a series of resizes, the order will get progressively more and more scrambled.

In short, what you are seeing is an artifact of the hash table implementation and the specific `hashCode` method.  It is not something that you can (or should) sensibly make use of.  Not least because it can change (*and has changed*) from one Java release to the next!

---

<sup>1 - Or in Java 8 or later, if congestion of a particular hash bucket / hash chain causes it to switch from a simple list to a red-black tree.  Deep implementation detail.  If you are curious, read the source code!</sup>

Answer (score 94):

From the Javadoc: [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) "class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

If you need consistent ordering, you can use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (for insertion/access order), or [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (for comparision order).  Please note, that these maintain the order of the keys, not the values.

Comment: I think the OP was asking why the HashMap *appears* to preserving insertion order in his use-case.  It is clear that he was *expecting* the iteration order to be more random.

Comment: Although the ordering is for the keys, most of these maps actually store key/value entries (`Map.Entry`). Thus, values will most usually also appear in the same order as their associated keys.

Comment: There is a difference between "we don't guarantee the order" and "we guarantee the order will look and/or actually be random". There's no reason for OP to expect that the data will look random.

Answer (score 11):

A [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is what you're after.  From the doco, it *differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries*

Answer (score 7):

Try LinkedHashMap if order is important... see from JavaDoc

> public class LinkedHashMap extends
>   HashMap
>
> Hash table and linked list
>   implementation of the Map interface,
>   with predictable iteration order. This
>   implementation differs from HashMap in
>   that it maintains a doubly-linked list
>   running through all of its entries.
>   This linked list defines the iteration
>   ordering, which is normally the order
>   in which keys were inserted into the
>   map (insertion-order). Note that
>   insertion order is not affected if a
>   key is re-inserted into the map. (A
>   key k is reinserted into a map m if
>   m.put(k, v) is invoked when
>   m.containsKey(k) would return true
>   immediately prior to the invocation.)

Answer (score 1):

A related collection is java.util.concurrent's [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).  A [skiplist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) allows you to traverse the entries in key order and also look them in random order (but not as fast as a HashMap).

There's a nice skiplist [demo applet](http://people.ksp.sk/~kuko/bak/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2144822/642706) is correct, explaining the details behind what you saw.

In addition, as of Java 21 there is another way to view the matter. Java 21 brought us [sequenced collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

## `SequencedMap`

Map implementations with a defined encounter order are now represented by the interface [`SequencedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html), as of Java 21+.

Maps whose entries are ordered based on the content of the key have long been represented by the interface `SortedMap` and its successor [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html). But these two interfaces did not cover other orders. Specifically these did not cover the [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) that tracks insertion-order.

The new `SequencedMap` interface covers all of these. Every map interface and implementation built into Java with a defined encounter order is covered by `SequencedMap`.

So we can answer your question “Does HashMap maintain an encounter order based on insertion?” merely by glancing at the Javadoc for `SequencedMap`.  That interface’s Javadoc lists three concrete implementations, and `HashMap` is *not* one of them. So, no, `HashMap` does not maintain an encounter order.

Answer (score -1):

No, the order is not preserved in case of HashMap (if you want sorted implementation.)
In case you want keys to be sorted, you can use TreeMap.

for example -
{[3=1],[2=50],[20=4],[14=1]} -> HashMap

for TreeMap, you get -
{[2=50],[3=1],[14=1],[20=4]} -> TreeMap