# How does Java order items in a HashMap or a HashTable?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable, hashmap, hashcode

I was wondering how Java orders items in the `Map` (`HashMap` or `Hashtable`) when they are added. Are the keys ordered by the hashcode, memory reference or by allocation precedence...?

It's because I've noticed same pairs in the `Map` are not always in the same order

Answer (score 126, accepted):

[`java.util.HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is unordered; you can't and shouldn't assume anything beyond that.

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

[`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) uses insertion-order.

> This implementation differs from `HashMap` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

[`java.util.TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), a [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), uses either natural or custom ordering of the keys.

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Comment: yet a Hashmap follows the same predictable sequence every time... why?

Comment: @pop stack HashMap does not guarantee the order. See Stephen C's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144776/order-of-values-retrieved-from-a-hashmap for details on how and why it might change.

Comment: These kind of answer are great! A cheat sheet would be awesome for listing differences between all the Map, List, Set in Java!

Comment: @popstack It follows the same order for the same data because the order is not random. Its the same data processed by the same algorithm, so its no surpise its in the same order. Don't confuse being unordered with being randomly placed!

Answer (score 19):

First of all: `HashMap` specifically **doesn't** provide a stable and/or defined ordering. So anything you observe is simply an implementation detail and you **must not** depend on it in any way.

Since it is sometimes useful to know the reason for the seemingly random ordering, here's the basic idea:

A `HashMap` has number of buckets (implemented as an array) in which to store entries.

When an item is added to the map, it is assigned to a buckets based on a value derived of its `hashCode` and the bucket size of the `HashMap`. (Note that it's possible that the bucket is already occupied, which is called a collision. That's handled gracefully and correctly, but I'll ignore that handling for the description because it doesn't change the concept).

The perceived ordering of the entires (such as returned by iterating over the `Map`) depends on the order of the entries in those buckets.

Whenever the size is rehashed (because the map exceeded its fullness threshold), then the number of buckets changes, which means that the position of each element might change, since the bucket position is derived from the number of buckets as well.

Answer (score 5):

`HashMap` does not sort at all. For a map that sorts by key values you should use `TreeMap` instead.

From the JavaDocs for `TreeMap`:

> Red-Black tree based implementation of
>   the SortedMap interface. This class
>   guarantees that the map will be in
>   ascending key order, sorted according
>   to the natural order for the key's
>   class (see Comparable), or by the
>   comparator provided at creation time,
>   depending on which constructor is
>   used.

From the documentation of `HashMap`:

> This class makes no guarantees as to
>   the order of the map; in particular,
>   it does not guarantee that the order
>   will remain constant over time.

Comment: I never said I wanted them sorted. I was wondering if java does

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` is not an ordered data structure - you should not rely on entries in a `HashMap` being in a certain order. Some `Map` implementations such as `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap` do guarantee a certain order, but `HashMap` does not.

If you really want to know what happens internally, lookup the source code of `HashMap` - you can find it in **src.zip** which should be in your JDK installation directory.

A `HashMap` has a number of "buckets" in which it stores its entries. Which bucket an entry is stored in is determined by the hash code of the key of the entry. The order in which you see the entries in the `HashMap` depends on the hash codes of the keys. But don't write programs that rely on entries being in a certain order in a `HashMap` - the implementation might change in a future version of Java and your program then would not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

hashmap has a not defined order of the elements

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined ordering in a hash table. Keys are placed into a slot, based on the hash code, but even that isn't a trivial order-by-hash-code.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap stores the values using the unique hash-value generated using a part of the key. This hash-value maps to the address where it is going to be stored. This is how it ensures an access O(1).

LinkedHashmap on the other hand preserves the order in which you added to the map.

Comment: HashMap can't guarantee O(1). It tries to do it's best about it, but in the worst case it's O(n) with n=number of entries (even if this is unlikely (or your hashCode method is really bad implemented))

Comment: Agreed that it does not always provide a constant-time performance, but more often than not, it does try to.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html