# How to fetch first 10 key value pairs in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am trying to iterate only the first "n" values in my Map, is there any method available or i need to control it only with a count variable.

Below is an example, i have sorted a group of names belong to the same city. Now i only want the first 10 city and the person names in it.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    List<String> list = entry.getValue();
    // Display list of people in City
}
```

Is there a Map implementation that can hold fixed number of key,value pairs?
Please get some directions.

Thanks,

-Vijay Selvaraj

Comment: Do you want to prevent adding more than 10 entries, or do you want any 10 entries, or do you want the 10 first entries added? More details.

Comment: My target is to have 10 entries. Now i am making it full and then taking a subset of the whole. But i can very well stop when i reach 10 entries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to fetch first 10 key value pairs in `HashMap`

`HashMap` [is unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817728/367273). This makes the question ill-posed (unless by "first" you mean "arbitrary").

If you want a consistent ordering of keys, you need to change the type of your map to a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), such as [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Alternatively, if it's the oldest elements you're after (i.e. the ones you've inserted first), then [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is the answer.

As to actually getting the first `n` elements, a loop with a counter is a pretty reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

> *I am trying to iterate only the first "n" values in my Map, is there any method available or i need to control it only with a count variable.*

The closest thing you'll find using only the standard Collections API (which still is slightly worse than a counter variable IMO) is the following:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entryList =
        new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>(map.entrySet());

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entryList.subList(0, 10)) {
    List<String> list = entry.getValue();
    // Display list of people in City
}
```

The lengthy type parameters could be avoided either by using the fancy diamond from Java 7:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
```

or by using iterating over the keys and `.get` the corresponding values.

Comment: Just looked at both Hashmap and Set, there is no subList method, care to tell us where that came from?

Comment: @Churk: It came from the `ArrayList` that got constructed with the contents of `map.entrySet()`.

Comment: @aix map.entrySet() returns a set, not an arraylist

Comment: @Churk: Right. And the `new ArrayList<...>(...)` creates the `ArrayList` on which `subList()` is then called.

Comment: @Churk, I go via the [`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) constructor. Clarified code in the answer slightly.

Comment: I tried it out but the compiler complains "The constructor ArrayList<String>(Set<Map.Entry<String,String>>) is undefined"

Comment: Sorry. `...` should be `Map.Entry<String,String>`. I'll update the answer to be more complete.

Comment: @aioobe so there is an implied casting from a set to arraylist. I been away from the java for a few years, and just haven't seen it done this way before.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<string>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  if (list.size() > 9) break;
    list.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: OP stated that he knows how to do this with counter variable