# HashMap where the order of keys is important

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I use HashMaps for storing sets of  pairs, but I also have to be sure from the first json serialization (from a Php client) and to the Java HashMap set browsing, the **order** of keys will be the same

```
//import com.google.gson.Gson;
//import com.google.common.base.Joiner;  
String s = "{\"durant\":\"kevin\", \"james\":\"lebron\",\"harden\":\"james\",\"westbrook\":\"russel\"}";
System.out.println(s);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type typeOfMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, String> m = gson.fromJson(s, typeOfMap);
List<String> entries = new ArrayList< String>(m.keySet());
//Collections.sort(entries);
System.out.println(entries);
System.out.println(m.entrySet());
System.out.println( Joiner.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("").join(m) );
```

It seems working for small sets of values, without sorting again (Here by keys alphabetically), but is it a reliable way to do? could the order change between the json String and the Map browsing?

**Edit**: probably LinkedHashMap is more order preserving?

Comment: Where exactly is a HashMap being used?

Comment: good point, just the Map interface, So the order should never differ from the input String?

Comment: Be aware that `LinkedHashMap` doesn't change the order if you re-insert keys (i.e. call `put(k,v)` when `containsKey(k)` returns true). That may or may not be the behaviour you desire!

Comment: LinkedHashMap  doesn't overwrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) maintains insertion-order. Beyond that there are various [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementations such as [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 1):

From this chart, you can see different behaviors among the various implementations of `Map` bundled with Java 11. Note the "iteration order" column.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

If you want the map to maintain an order based on sorting by the value of the keys, use an implementation that implements `SortedMap`, or its successor, `NavigableMap`. That means either `TreeMap`, or if you need concurrency, `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

If you want to maintain the original insertion order, use `LinkedHashMap`.

If you have enum objects as key, use `EnumMap` to maintain the keys in order that the enum was defined.

All the other `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11 make no promises about order of the  keys, so avoid them. You may also consider using 3rd-party implementations of `Map` such as those found in *Google Guava* library.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this question on SO:
[How does Java order items in a HashMap or a HashTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817695/how-does-java-order-items-in-a-hashmap-or-a-hashtable?rq=1)

May give you a clearer picture...