# Put keys in hashmap and retrieve in same order

Tags: java, hashmap

Below is a piece of code which I use for inserting the values in a hashmap.

```
String[] folders={"Movies/HD/By Genre/Action","Movies/HD/By Genre/Comedy"};
HashMap<String, String> sdsResults = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(int i=0; i<folders.length; i++){
    sdsResults.put(folders[i], null);
}

Iterator<String> itr = sdsResults.keySet().iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("keys in map are = "+itr.next());
}
```

The output is -

```
keys in map are = Movies/HD/By Genre/Comedy
keys in map are = Movies/HD/By Genre/Action
```

Now I wanted to keys to come in the same order as how I had put in. i.e. first the Action one should come and then the Comedy. But reverse order is coming.

Can someone explain why is it so? And I want the order to be the same as the folder contents. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The order of keys in a hash is not defined. You want a map. [Here's](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq19-containers.html#associativecontainers) a comparison of the internals.

Basically, when you put something in a hash, you scramble the key. This is a [one-way function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). The *whole point* is that you can't un-do it -- it's a way of putting 100 things in 10 boxes.

Comment: So is there any other way to get the keys in a specific order.Any other collection type that I can use

Comment: A map is the correct abstract data type. There may be different implementations (binary trees, skip lists, ... )

Comment: Of course you could aleways maintain a separate vector of your keys!

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap should solve the problem of ordering.
Similar question and the answer here [Order of values retrieved from a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144776/order-of-values-retrieved-from-a-hashmap)

Answer (score -1):

You can use ListOrderedMap from Apache's Commons-Collection library to keep the order.