# HashMap order of insertion

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Why does the HashMap retrieve in an ordered manner, when it is know that HashMap stores and retrieves element in an unordered manner

```
HashMap m = new HashMap();
m.put("A", 1);
m.put("B", 2);
m.put("C", 3);
m.put("D", 4);
m.put("E", 5);

Set keySet = m.keySet();
Iterator it = keySet.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(m.get(it.next()));
}
```

OUTPUT - 1
2
3
4
5

Comment: *"when it is know that HashMap stores and retrieves element in an unordered manner"* Just to make that clear: this doesn't mean that `HashMap` will jumble your elements just to be unordered. It just means that you can't rely on any order. It still can happen that you can get and "ordered" output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just happened that `hashCodes` of A B C D E are ordered increasingly in this particular case.

```
 while(it.hasNext())
 {
    String next = it.next();
    System.out.println(next.hashCode() + " "+ m.get(next));
 }
```

Will produce the following

```
65 1
66 2
67 3
68 4
69 5
```

However, this doesn't mean that every time you have an increasingly ordered set of hash codes, map-entries will be stored in their hashCodes' order.

Comment: Just because the hashes are ordered doesn't mean they're ordered in the actual `HashMap`.  There's some more messing around with the hash code before it actually gets used as the index.

Comment: sure, the mod hash and the hash table size plays a role, I don't know how to word this though :(

Comment: That's pretty much why I didn't try.  The messing about can take any form, and _does_ vary between different Java implementations; the order for these elements would be different in different Java versions.  That's why I deliberately left it open-ended why these elements got put in the right order: because there was never any guarantee that they'd stay in the right order.

Comment: it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2144822/869736 actually has a pretty great answer.  I'm inclined to mark this as a duplicate just for that answer being really good.

Answer (score 3):

In short: *you got lucky.*  `HashMap` generally returns elements in an arbitrary nonsensical order, and this case happened to be one where all the elements came out in order.

Comment: But everytime i run this. It gives me the same order

Comment: HashMap's implementation relies on the keys' hashCode, which for strings will be the same for each run. Try changing your keys and see what happens.

Comment: @ArijitDasgupta It's not random, it's just not specified.  The implementation makes no guarantees.  It's not the run that got lucky, it's your choice of keys that got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Because of 2 things:

- [The implementation of `String`'s `hashCode()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29).

This is the implementation of `hashCode()` for `String`:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

For one-character strings, it's simply the Unicode value of that character.  Those letters (A-E) have consecutive values (65-69).

The [`HashMap` class modifies the hash a little bit](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28java.lang.Object%29), but in this case with such low values, the value is unaffected.

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

- [The default number of buckets in a `HashMap` is `16`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap--).

[`HashMap` will reduce the hash code modulo the number of buckets](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.putVal%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29) to find the bucket number for the key.  In this case, the bucket number are all sequential -- `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.  So, the iterator iterated over the buckets in order.

If any of these things were to happen, some of which are not in the `HashMap` contract and are not in your control, then the iteration order may change.

- Add other keys that don't have the same quotient modulo 16, e.g. "Z", "a", "AA".
- Create a map with a smaller default capacity.
- Java decides to mess with the `hash` method internal to `HashMap`.
- Java decides to mess with the algorithm mapping the hash code to the bucket number internal to `HashMap`.
- Java decides to mess with the `hashCode` method in `String`.