# To remove key from hashmap and rearrange keys when used in recycler view

Tags: android, hashmap, android-recyclerview

Please any one can help how to remove particular key from hashmap and then rearrange the keys in hashmap accordingly.

Below is my code.

```
Set<Integer> integerSet = hashMap.keySet();
                int removekey = pos;
                ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Integer integer : integerSet) {
                    if (integer > removekey) {
                        integers.add(integer);
                    }
                }

                for (Integer integer : integers) {
                    if (hashMap.containsKey(integer)) {
                        AddCardPojo pojo = hashMap.get(integer);
                        pojo.setImagCard(cardImage[integer - 1]);
                        hashMap.remove(integer);
                        hashMap.put(integer - 1, pojo);
                    }
                }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I have attached screenshot of error

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by re arrange? can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I mean when I add more than 7 items in hashmap and try to remove 4th item from hashmap then it gives me error "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: can you add the exception in the question?

Comment: pojo.setImagCard(cardImage[integer - 1]); is probably where you have the exception

Comment: @Suraj. ok. thanx.  Will look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can directly remove a key value pair,you can directly do

```
 hashMap.remove(removeKey);
```

as for 're arranging keys in hashmap',
it is a data structure which makes no guarantees of order of data.
[Check this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144776/order-of-values-retrieved-from-a-hashmap)

If you need a particular order as per integer, you could use arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Finally it could be done.
Below is my answer.

```
               hashMap.remove(key);

               List<AddCardPojo> hashMapsList=new ArrayList<>();

                Iterator it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {

                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    hashMapsList.add((AddCardPojo) pair.getValue());
                }

                hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                for(int i=0; i<hashMapsList.size();i++){
                    hashMap.put(i,hashMapsList.get(i));
                }
```