# When iterating through a HashMap with Integer keys, will it always return keys in ascending order?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap defined as such:

`public Map<Integer, String> staticBlockPositions = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`

I am iterating over the map by getting each key, like this:

```
for (Integer key : blockPositions.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

My question is, can I rely on the value of `key` to always be in ascending order. So if my HashMap looks something like this:

```
{
    4: "abc123",
    1: "def456",
    11: "qwe789",
    10: "iop019"
}
```

(I know this is JSON format, this is just so you get an idea of the data set).

Will my loop **always** output

```
1
4
10
11
```

regardless of the order of my data?

**Important to note, the order in which the keys are add is completely random, and I cannot control what key is added when.**

This is for a Tetris style game, so getting the keys in ascending order is a **must**.

Comment: Are you sure `Map` is the data structure you want to use?

Comment: look at TreeMap

Comment: There is a very simple way you can find this out. You do not need us for it. It is testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

There is no special case for integer keys. You simply can't rely upon the order.

If you want the keys to be in ascending order, use an implementation of `SortedMap`, like [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: TreeMap is what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: While what you say is absolutely correct, the order of the keys in a `HashMap<Integer,?>` is predictable *to a limited degree*; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2144822/139985.  (But this fact is not something that it is sane to try to rely on in an application.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @AndyTurner stated about `HashMap` not guaranteeing order, it appears that [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) provides the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No,

1. To maintain sorted order, use TreeMap.
2. To maintain insertion order, use LinkedHashMap.