# Why Hash Table Output Values in Decremental Order

Tags: java, iteration, hashtable

When we output the values of a simple hashtable why it's values output in *decremented* order of it's key?

And how can I output in *incremental* order?

```
   Hashtable<Integer, String> htable = new Hashtable<>();
        htable.put(100, "Dil");
        htable.put(200, "Vidu");
        htable.put(300, "Apeksha");
        htable.put(400, "Akalpa");
        htable.put(500, "Akash");
        for (Map.Entry entry : htable.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  :  " + entry.getValue() + "  :  " + entry.hashCode());
        }
```

**Output**

```
500  :  Akash  :  63312920
400  :  Akalpa  :  1962708790
300  :  Apeksha  :  861238907
200  :  Vidu  :  2666092
100  :  Dil  :  68611
```

Also Can you please explain what actually **hashcode** is? Is that a random number set to make each result is unique?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no guarantee regarding the order you get when you iterate the keys in a Java HashMap, and the documentation states this.  If you want a sorted map, look into using something like `TreeMap`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. Yes I easily can. I was just following a tutorial and wandered what was the reason.

Comment: I didn't give an exact duplicate, but the explanation is the same.

Comment: Please use `LinkedHashMap` as it maintains insertion order. `Hashtable` and `HashMap` does not maintain insertion order.`entry.hashCode()` represents unique code for a given key-value pair. Technically, it is `XOR` between key hash code and value hash code.

Comment: @anshul what did you mean by `it isXOR between key hash code and value hash code` ???

Comment: This is logic to calculate hash code (i.e. unique number) for Map.entry object and logic is First, get key hash code and then value hash code and then perform XOR operation between the two hash codes.

Comment: @pippilongstocking Hashcode is a output generated by a hash function, in case of hashtable the key is the input to a hash function.

Comment: @pippilongstocking see the documentation regarding `hashCode()` here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode() It is inherited from the `Object` class. Note that it is not guaranteed to be unique across any set of objects, but there is a good chance that it will be.

Comment: I have added [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144776/is-the-order-of-values-retrieved-from-a-hashmap-the-insertion-order) where someone else observed (serendipitous) key ordering.  The answer says why it happened ... and that you can't rely on it.