# Don't where my data sequence are changing hashmap

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, hashmap

I had a `list` and each item of the list has its `parent id`. I created `hashmap` which contain list `item`
as per its `parentId`. The list is in proper sequence and I add `item` to `hashmap`. In the end, the hashmap sequence changed. I don't know where.

```
var package = HashMap<String, MutableList<Model>>()
var temp: MutableList<Model>? = ArrayList<Model>()
for (item in list!!) {
    temp = package?.get(item.parentId!!)
    Log.e("parent id",Gson().toJson(item.parentId!!))
    if (temp != null)
        temp.add(item)
    else {
        temp = ArrayList<Model>()
        temp.add(item)
    }

    package?.put(item.parentId!!, temp)
    Log.e("package",Gson().toJson(package.keys))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144776/is-the-order-of-values-retrieved-from-a-hashmap-the-insertion-order

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the `HashMap` sequence will be the same as how you inserted. Use `LinkedHashSet` if you would like to preserve the order. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-set/index.html